# ¿Inicializar la referencia de un arreglo en el constructor?

Tags: java

```
public class Dados{
   int numeros[];

   Dados(){
      numeros = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
   }
}
```

NetBeans me marca un error. ¿Cómo puedo inicializar el arreglo en el constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese tipo de inicializador solo puede utilizarse en la declaración de la variable.

```
int numeros[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Si quieres inicializar la variable `numeros` en el constructor debes hacerlo así:

```
Dados() {
    numeros = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
}
```

Comment: Eso es porque los arreglos son objetos, verdad E. Betanzos?

Comment: Ya he leído otras respuestas de la inicializacion de arreglos y llegue a la siguientes conclusion;

Comment: Java permite declarar un objeto arreglo sin constructor si y solo si esta declaración  es en una sola linea.

En otro caso es necesario utilizar el constructor para crear el arreglo.

Corrijanme si estoy mal en algo o hace falta alguna otra explicación.

Comment: Es más o menos como comentas. Te pongo un enlace al capítulo relacionada con arreglos de la especificación del lenguaje Java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/arrays.html